# IFS not refuses to return an array

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

**Data**

```
<CellA1="One">
```

**My Problem:**

I'm using a simple `IF` function `IF(A1="One", named_range_one)` and it works like charm and returned the `named_range_one`. But as soon as I use `IFS` it stops returning my named range. It seems like a bug or phrasing error for me. I also tried to wrap it into an `ARRAYFORMULA` but that didn't work out as well.
So `IFS(A1="One", named_range_one, A1="Two", named_range_two)` as soon as I use IFS my function stops working and returns the error "An array value could not be found".
I can't find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Your `IFS()` formula works in Excel 365.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need nested `IF`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1="One", named_range_one, 
              IF(A1="Two", named_range_two, )))
```

see: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124685/186471**

Comment: Thank you for that feedback. Such a pity that `IFS()` is not returning the array. It makes my anyway very long function even more complicated to read. At least your solution works. I appreciate your answer!